# How to triple JOIN tables to perform a query with OR operand in MySQL [Specific Case]

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Hello dear SO community,

I have been struggling with this for some time now and since time is running out I turn to you.

I have these tables:

```
USERS:
user_id (PK)
user_name

PROJECTS:
project_id (PK)
project_name
user_id (FK) - referring to the creator of the project
```

Users and projects are in M:N relationship, which is captured in table PERMISSIONS.

```
PERMISSIONS:
project_id (FK)
user_id (FK)
```

Permissions row holds a access rule for single user and single project. If a pair for given user and project does not exist in the table, that user cannot access that project.

I am trying to query all projects that current user should have access to, meaning those that he created and those that he is associated with in the PERMISSIONS table but with every project I want the user_name of its creator. I supply current user ID to a prepared statement in PHP, which works fine, but I cannot seem to get the query right. I have been able

I was able to to get projects that were created or accessible by certain user, but I cannot figure out how to join USERS, to get the user_name of user_id in projects (username of the project creator) that I query.

I am querying something along the lines of:

```
SELECT projects.name as name, projects.project_id as project_id, projects.user_id  as user_id, users.name as user_name
FROM projects JOIN permissions USING (project_id) JOIN users USING (user_id) WHERE permissions.user_id=:user_id OR 
projects.user_id=:user_id ORDER BY name
```

Comment: @janetuism, sorry I misunderstood your question. It appears that the other two answers are on the right track, so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities:

1. Have a `join` on projects with `or`, to fetch both creators and those with permission. A `join` with `or` is generally not advisable because it leads to table scans. `Distinct` is needed

   ```
   select distinct u.user_name, p.project_name
   from users u
   left join permissions pm on pm.user_id = u.user_id
   left join projects p on p.user_id = u.user_id or p.project_id = pm.project_id
   where u.user_id = 2;
   ```
2. `Cross join projects` and have the 'or's in the `where` clause. Need `distinct`.

   ```
    select distinct u.user_name, p.project_name
    from users u
    cross join projects p
    left join permissions pm on pm.user_id = u.user_id
    where u.user_id = 2 and ( p.project_id = pm.project_id or  p.user_id = u.user_id );
   ```
3. Use `union`, one `select` for creators and one for those with permission. `Distinct` is not needed because `union` does `distinct`

   ```
      select u.user_name, p.project_name
      from users u
      inner join projects p on p.user_id = u.user_id
      where u.user_id = 2
    union 
      select u.user_name, p.project_name
      from users u
      inner join permissions pm on pm.user_id = u.user_id
      inner join projects p on p.project_id = pm.project_id
      where u.user_id = 2
   ```

online editor here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3y64ukxtp

Comment: Tried all the approaches, but it only returns one project even if user should have access to multiple and returns the first user_name in permissions instead of the user_name of the creator stated in projects as user_id attribute

Comment: Hi, in the online editor it fetches multiple projects, one per permission, in addition to creator started projects. If you post the complete schema I could adapt the queries to it

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your query is that the `user_id` field should be both matched:

- between `users` and `permissions`, to catch projects the user is allowed to work on
- between `users` and `projects`, to catch projects the user has created

One way of solving this issue is to have a `UNION` operation between these two result sets. In order to make the joins more efficient, it's better to move the filtering operation (finding the specific user) before the join operation, that's the reason why I've moved it into a subquery (under the shape of common table expression - cte).

```
WITH user_details AS(
    SELECT user_id, 
           user_name 
    FROM users
    WHERE user_id = 501
)
SELECT user_details.*,
       projects.project_id,
       projects.project_name,
       projects.user_id         AS project_creator
FROM       user_details 
INNER JOIN projects     
        ON user_details.user_id = projects.user_id 

UNION 

SELECT user_details.*,
       projects.project_id,
       projects.project_name,
       projects.user_id         AS project_creator
FROM       user_details 
INNER JOIN permissions 
        ON user_details.user_id = permissions.user_id
INNER JOIN projects
        ON permissions.project_id = projects.project_id
```

You can try it in a sample environment [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jrPBzNwmRAoKvB1cVPpfXm/1).

Comment: The query makes me face the initial problem. Throws an error on different number of columns (even in the sample enviroment) and since I lack deeper understanding of joins and the visualisation skills, I don't know how to fix this query </3

Comment: Here is my fault: I may have forgotten to fix columns. Updated this answer with a tested solution: try it now. @janetusim

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
SELECT project_id FROM projects WHERE user_id = :user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT project_id FROM permissions WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

you get the ids of all projects that `:user_id` created or has access to.

Use it with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT p.*, u.user_name
FROM projects p INNER JOIN users u
ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE p.project_id IN (
  SELECT project_id FROM projects WHERE user_id = :user_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT project_id FROM permissions WHERE user_id = :user_id
);
```